# How to install CSS for react-redux-toastr

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've tried to use [`react-redux-toastr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-toastr) for notifications, but I can't make the CSS load properly. I use `webpack` to bundle, in `LoginForm.js` the `LoginForm.css` is loaded correctly and takes effect (the green background comes from there), the `react-redux-toastr.min.css` for `react-redux-toastr` doesn't work. I tried including it in the file where the toaster is fired and in the root, but none of them helped. Since `webpack` compiles it should satisfy all the `import`-s.

***Please help me debug and fix this issue.***

[image: No CSS]

appClient.js

```
...
import RootReducer from './reducers/flightControlApp';
import './components/style/react-redux-toastr.min.css';
import ReduxToastr from 'react-redux-toastr';

...

let store = compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)) (createStore) (
    RootReducer,
    persistedState
);

...

window.onload = () => 
{
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <Provider store={ store }>
                <div>
                    <ReduxToastr
                            timeOut={15000}
                            newestOnTop={false}
                            preventDuplicates
                            position="top-left"
                            transitionIn="fadeIn"
                            transitionOut="fadeOut"
                            progressBar
                            closeOnToastrClick/>
                    <AppRoutes />
                </div>
            </Provider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
        document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

./reducers/flightControlApp.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import UserReducer from './userReducer';
import UserStatsReducer from './userStatsReducer';
import {reducer as toastrReducer} from 'react-redux-toastr'

let rootReducer = combineReducers({
    userState: UserReducer,
    statsState: UserStatsReducer,
    toastr: toastrReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './style/LoginForm.css';
import { toastr } from 'react-redux-toastr';
import { PulseLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { assert } from 'chai';

class LoginForm extends React.Component{

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.isLoginError)
        {
            toastr.error('Error:', 'Login failed', {
                onShowComplete: this.props.onResetLoginCallback,
                onToastrClick: this.props.onResetLoginCallback
            });
        }
    }

 render() {
   ...
  }
 }
```

Comment: try adding this in your index.html file:`<link href="https://diegoddox.github.io/react-redux-toastr/7.1/react-redux-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: I suggest checking out `notistack`, I went down the same path as you did when choosing a toast system and ended up picking it over toastr.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using npm package the `react-redux-toastr` CSS/Sass file is also available for use. Base on [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-toastr) and your codebase.

`appClient.js`

```
import RootReducer from './reducers/flightControlApp';
import 'react-redux-toastr/lib/css/react-redux-toastr.min.css'; // it's coming from node_modules
// instead of import './components/style/react-redux-toastr.min.css';
import ReduxToastr from 'react-redux-toastr';
```

or import it to the main CSS if you have one;

`appclient.css` or `appclient.scss`

```
@import 'react-redux-toastr/src/styles/index'; // string import
@import url('react-redux-toastr/src/styles/index') // or url import
```

[check import rules in css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp). I used `react-redux-toastr 7.6.4`.

And Webpack CSS plugin.

```
// module import section

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/styles.css');

// Webpack css plugin configurations
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
              {
               loader: 'css-loader',
             },
             {
               loader: 'sass-loader',
             },
           ],
      }),
   },
]},
plugins: [extractTextPlugin]
```